# How do I fix the error that's causing Video Repair Tool not to run in Wine?

Tags: wine

#### Summary

1. I have a Windows program called "Grau GmbH Video Repair Tool" (for repairing
   MP4 videos), and I'm running it with Wine (Windows emulator) in Linux. But
   before the Repair Tool GUI even displays, I get an error saying

   ```
   wine: Unhandled page fault on read access
   ```

   and the program doesn't run.
2. I run the program at a konsole, using

   ```
   $ wine gs.exe
   ```

   (`gs.exe` is the name of the Video Repair Tool.)

   And the console output is as follows:

   ```
   hInst=4194304
   RegWnd=49200
   script file found
   hWnd=131174
   button=1006e
   click 1006e
   s=onchooselang()
   lang=en
   SCRIPTFOLDER=Z:\home\knoppix\grau gmbh video repair tool\videorepair\
   TOOLSFOLDER=
   HOMEFOLDER=C:\users\knoppix\
   checking file: Z:\home\knoppix\grau gmbh video repair
   tool\videorepair\movdump.exe
   success
   checking toolsfolder: Z:\home\knoppix\grau gmbh video repair
   tool\videorepair\toolswin\
   success
   checking file: Z:\home\knoppix\grau gmbh video repair
   tool\videorepair\toolswin\mencoder.exe
   success
   checking file: Z:\home\knoppix\grau gmbh video repair
   tool\videorepair\toolswin\mplayer.exe
   success
   checking file: Z:\home\knoppix\grau gmbh video repair
   tool\videorepair\movdump.exe
   success
   fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity ((nil),-1,(nil),(nil),0,3,(nil),0,(nil)) - stub!
   fixme:wbemprox:wbem_locator_ConnectServer 0x15d488, L"root\\cimv2", (null),
   (null), (null), 0x00000000, (null), (nil), 0x32d1c0)
   wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000000 at address 0x404651
   (thread 0009), starting debugger...
   ```

   The last message seems to be what's wrong, ie "wine: Unhandled page fault ...".
3. Please could you suggest what I need to do to make the program work. Thanks.

#### Full Details

**NOTE:** "My Wine version is 1.5.4".

1. I downloaded `gs.exe` from
   http://grauonline.de/cms2/?page_id=5
2. My system is Debian.
3. When I run `wine gs.exe`, a separate (Wine?) GUI box appears, asking me to
   select English or Chinese, and I pick English.

   Then the output at "Summary 2." appears on the console, followed by another
   (Wine?) GUI box which says in part "The program `gs.exe` has encountered a serious problem ... This can be caused by a problem in the program or a deficiency in Wine. ...".

   When I click Close in that box, the console DEBUG output is displayed, which
   I've shown at 7. below.
4. A user at
   https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1298337.html
   (user nero76 at end of webpage), says that the Video Repair Tool works in Wine
   for him, although he calls it `guiscript.exe`, not `gs.exe`.
5. I've tried the following fixes, but always get the same error, as already described:

   **a)** In `winecfg`, I set `gs.exe` to run under Windows 7 (which the Grau GmbH website at 1. says it will run under (amongst other Windows versions)).
   **b)** I've set Linux execute permission on `gs.exe`.
   **c)** Ran `sudo wine gs.exe`.
6. Other Windows programs work that were already on my system, like

   ```
   $ wine "/home/knoppix/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/cmd.exe"
   ```

   `cmd.exe` is the DOS command interpreter.
7. The following is the console DEBUG output from `wine gs.exe`, not shown in
   the Summary above:

   ```
    wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000000 at address 0x404651
   (thread 0009), starting debugger...
   Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code
   (0x00404651).
   Register dump:
    CS:0073 SS:007b DS:007b ES:007b FS:0033 GS:003b
    EIP:00404651 ESP:0032d1ac EBP:0032d740 EFLAGS:00210282(  R- --  I S - - - )
    EAX:00000000 EBX:00000000 ECX:00000000 EDX:00000081
    ESI:7e2e1400 EDI:0015d4a4
   Stack dump:
   0x0032d1ac:  0032d740 0032d604 7ebcd590 cccccccc
   0x0032d1bc:  cccccccc 00000000 0015d488 cccccccc
   0x0032d1cc:  cccccccc 0015d4a4 cccccccc 0032d5f8
   0x0032d1dc:  005ba558 7ebcd590 0032d5f8 00000004
   0x0032d1ec:  0032d5f8 004229d4 00000001 00000000
   0x0032d1fc:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
   Backtrace:
   =>0 0x00404651 in gs (+0x4651) (0x0032d740)
     1 0x00416af3 in gs (+0x16af2) (0x0032de3c)
     2 0x004111e1 in gs (+0x111e0) (0x0032df18)
     3 0x0040ce4a in gs (+0xce49) (0x0032e004)
     4 0x004102c6 in gs (+0x102c5) (0x0032e130)
     5 0x00411614 in gs (+0x11613) (0x0032e258)
     6 0x0040cd92 in gs (+0xcd91) (0x0032e374)
     7 0x00401601 in gs (+0x1600) (0x0032e44c)
     8 0x7eba6f9c in user32 (+0x96f9b) (0x0032e49c)
     9 0x7eba945d in user32 (+0x9945c) (0x0032e4ec)
     10 0x7eb69c41 in user32 (+0x59c40) (0x0032e55c)
     11 0x7eb70456 in user32 (+0x60455) (0x0032e5dc)
     12 0x7eb708cc SendMessageW+0x4b() in user32 (0x0032e62c)
     13 0x7eb1a012 in user32 (+0xa011) (0x0032e6ec)
     14 0x7eba68eb WINPROC_wrapper+0xba() in user32 (0x0032e71c)
     15 0x7eba684a WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0032e74c)
     16 0x7eba6f9c in user32 (+0x96f9b) (0x0032e79c)
     17 0x7eba96ea CallWindowProcW+0x59() in user32 (0x0032e7ec)
     18 0x004075ac in gs (+0x75ab) (0x0032e848)
     19 0x7eba6f9c in user32 (+0x96f9b) (0x0032e898)
     20 0x7eba846e in user32 (+0x9846d) (0x0032ed58)
     21 0x7eba94e2 in user32 (+0x994e1) (0x0032eda8)
     22 0x7eb6b8de DispatchMessageA+0x9d() in user32 (0x0032ee98)
     23 0x00402d80 in gs (+0x2d7f) (0x0032f010)
     24 0x00416af3 in gs (+0x16af2) (0x0032f70c)
     25 0x004111e1 in gs (+0x111e0) (0x0032f7e8)
     26 0x0040ce4a in gs (+0xce49) (0x0032f8d4)
     27 0x004102c6 in gs (+0x102c5) (0x0032fa00)
     28 0x00411614 in gs (+0x11613) (0x0032fb28)
     29 0x0040cd92 in gs (+0xcd91) (0x0032fc44)
     30 0x004029b7 in gs (+0x29b6) (0x0046b180)
   0x00404651: movl        0x0(%eax),%ecx
   Modules:
   Module  Address                 Debug info      Name (97 modules)
   PE        400000-  4a9000       Export          gs
   ELF     7b800000-7ba30000       Deferred        kernel32<elf>
     \-PE  7b810000-7ba30000       \               kernel32
   ELF     7bc00000-7bcc3000       Deferred        ntdll<elf>
     \-PE  7bc10000-7bcc3000       \               ntdll
   ELF     7bf00000-7bf03000       Deferred        <wine-loader>
   ELF     7d7e6000-7d7fb000       Deferred        wbemprox<elf>
     \-PE  7d7f0000-7d7fb000       \               wbemprox
   ELF     7d7fb000-7d804000       Deferred        libffi.so.6
   ELF     7d804000-7d80d000       Deferred        librt.so.1
   ELF     7d80d000-7d858000       Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
   ELF     7d858000-7d8bb000       Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
   ELF     7d8bb000-7d940000       Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
   ELF     7d940000-7d952000       Deferred        libtasn1.so.3
   ELF     7d952000-7d96a000       Deferred        libresolv.so.2
   ELF     7d96a000-7d977000       Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
   ELF     7d977000-7d9ab000       Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
   ELF     7d9ab000-7da85000       Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
   ELF     7da85000-7da98000       Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
   ELF     7da98000-7daa6000       Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
   ELF     7daa6000-7db6f000       Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
   ELF     7db6f000-7dbc0000       Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
   ELF     7dbc0000-7dc16000       Deferred        libcups.so.2
   ELF     7dc28000-7dc3a000       Deferred        gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
   ELF     7dc50000-7dc83000       Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
     \-PE  7dc60000-7dc83000       \               uxtheme
   ELF     7dc83000-7dc8d000       Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
   ELF     7dc90000-7dc94000       Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
   ELF     7dc94000-7dc99000       Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
   ELF     7dd5f000-7dd89000       Deferred        libexpat.so.1
   ELF     7dd89000-7ddbf000       Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
   ELF     7ddbf000-7ddce000       Deferred        libxi.so.6
   ELF     7ddce000-7ddd6000       Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
   ELF     7ddd6000-7dddf000       Deferred        libxrender.so.1
   ELF     7dddf000-7dde5000       Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
   ELF     7dde5000-7dde8000       Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
   ELF     7dde8000-7de09000       Deferred        imm32<elf>
     \-PE  7ddf0000-7de09000       \               imm32
   ELF     7de09000-7de2c000       Deferred        libxcb.so.1
   ELF     7de2c000-7df65000       Deferred        libx11.so.6
   ELF     7df65000-7df77000       Deferred        libxext.so.6
   ELF     7df77000-7df90000       Deferred        libice.so.6
   ELF     7df90000-7e018000       Deferred        winex11<elf>
     \-PE  7dfa0000-7e018000       \               winex11
   ELF     7e018000-7e031000       Deferred        libz.so.1
   ELF     7e031000-7e0cd000       Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
   ELF     7e0cd000-7e0f1000       Deferred        libtinfo.so.5
   ELF     7e0f1000-7e117000       Deferred        libncurses.so.5
   ELF     7e11a000-7e11f000       Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
   ELF     7e121000-7e127000       Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
   ELF     7e13b000-7e162000       Deferred        msacm32<elf>
     \-PE  7e140000-7e162000       \               msacm32
   ELF     7e162000-7e20f000       Deferred        winmm<elf>
     \-PE  7e170000-7e20f000       \               winmm
   ELF     7e20f000-7e287000       Deferred        gdiplus<elf>
     \-PE  7e220000-7e287000       \               gdiplus
   ELF     7e287000-7e2b8000       Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
     \-PE  7e290000-7e2b8000       \               ws2_32
   ELF     7e2b8000-7e3c8000       Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
     \-PE  7e2d0000-7e3c8000       \               oleaut32
   ELF     7e3c8000-7e43e000       Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
     \-PE  7e3d0000-7e43e000       \               rpcrt4
   ELF     7e43e000-7e545000       Deferred        ole32<elf>
     \-PE  7e460000-7e545000       \               ole32
   ELF     7e545000-7e57f000       Deferred        winspool<elf>
     \-PE  7e550000-7e57f000       \               winspool
   ELF     7e57f000-7e678000       Deferred        comctl32<elf>
     \-PE  7e590000-7e678000       \               comctl32
   ELF     7e678000-7e6e3000       Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
     \-PE  7e690000-7e6e3000       \               shlwapi
   ELF     7e6e3000-7e8f5000       Deferred        shell32<elf>
     \-PE  7e6f0000-7e8f5000       \               shell32
   ELF     7e8f5000-7e9d4000       Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
     \-PE  7e900000-7e9d4000       \               comdlg32
   ELF     7e9d4000-7ea35000       Deferred        advapi32<elf>
     \-PE  7e9e0000-7ea35000       \               advapi32
   ELF     7ea35000-7eaf5000       Deferred        gdi32<elf>
     \-PE  7ea40000-7eaf5000       \               gdi32
   ELF     7eaf5000-7ec34000       Dwarf           user32<elf>
     \-PE  7eb10000-7ec34000       \               user32
   ELF     7ef65000-7ef72000       Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
   ELF     7ef72000-7ef7e000       Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
   ELF     7ef7e000-7ef97000       Deferred        libnsl.so.1
   ELF     7ef97000-7efdc000       Deferred        libm.so.6
   ELF     7efdc000-7efe2000       Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
   ELF     7efe2000-7efe8000       Deferred        libuuid.so.1
   ELF     7efe8000-7f000000       Deferred        version<elf>
     \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000       \               version
   ELF     b7490000-b7493000       Deferred        libxau.so.6
   ELF     b7494000-b7499000       Deferred        libdl.so.2
   ELF     b7499000-b760a000       Deferred        libc.so.6
   ELF     b760b000-b7626000       Deferred        libpthread.so.0
   ELF     b7628000-b7630000       Deferred        libsm.so.6
   ELF     b7641000-b764a000       Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
   ELF     b764a000-b778c000       Dwarf           libwine.so.1
   ELF     b778e000-b77af000       Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
   ELF     ffffe000-fffff000       Deferred        [vdso].so
   Threads:
   process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
   00000008 (D) Z:\home\knoppix\grau gmbh video repair tool\videorepair\gs.exe
           00000009    0 <==
   0000000e services.exe
           0000001f    0
           0000001e    0
           00000015    0
           00000010    0
           0000000f    0
   00000012 winedevice.exe
           0000001a    0
           00000019    0
           00000014    0
           00000013    0
   0000001b plugplay.exe
           00000020    0
           0000001d    0
           0000001c    0
   00000021 explorer.exe
           00000022    0
   $
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the software and unziped it to a temporarily directory /tmp/tim/videorepair. The wine version I use is 1.8. It works on my ubuntu machine. First I have to select a language, followed by a small demo mode message window and then the application opens.

```
cd /tmp/tim/videorepair
WINEPREFIX="/tmp/tim/wine_gs" WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot
WINEPREFIX="/tmp/tim/wine_gs" WINEARCH=win32 wine gs.exe
```